# odoo get compute fields of inherit models

Tags: inheritance, field, odoo

I have write a class that inherit of **purchase.order**,so i want to get the value of the "amount_untaxed" which is a computed field.
I have try this code :

```
class PurchaseOrderInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit='purchase.order'
    test_value=fields.Float(string='test value')

@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    vals['test_value']=self.amount_untaxed
    print(vals['test_value'])
    return super(PurchaseOrderInherit,self).create(vals)
```

But the Print function return 0.0.
Please someone helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computed field are computed in the create call, if you want to get the value:

```py
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    # create returns the newly created record
    rec = super(PurchaseOrderInherit,self).create(vals)
    print(rec.amount_untaxed)
    # if you want to set the value just do this
    rec.test_value = rec.amount_untaxed  # this will trigger write call to update the field in database
    return rec
```

Answer (score 1):

A computed field is computed on-the-fly. The value of `self.amount_untaxed` will not be available until you call `super`.

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    res = super(PurchaseOrderInherit,self).create(vals)
    print(res.test_value)
    return res
```

If `test_value` field is a computed field, instead of calculating its value in `create` and `write` methods you have just to override the same method that calculates
`amount_untaxed` value.